# Displaying Velodyne - HDL 32E data in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I tried to display converted HDL 32E data in rviz.

According to the wiki there is a launchfile, that takes the raw data from ethernet packets and converts them to PCL2-data.

Till that point it seems to work, I can at least launch the file and take data from a *.pcap file and get no warnings or errors.

Actual problem is:

rxgraph displays two topics to subscribe(/velodyne_nodelet_manager/bond and /velodyne_packets) - but if I add a PCL2 Display in rviz and subscribe to either, all I get is this:

> [ERROR] [1338812341.289971935]: Client
> [/rviz_1338811589243214356] wants
> topic /velodyne_packets to have
> datatype/md5sum
> [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181],
> but our version has
> [velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan/50804fc9533a0e579e6322c04ae70566].
> Dropping connection.
>
> [ERROR] [1338812407.808332750]: Client
> [/rviz_1338811589243214356] wants
> topic /velodyne_nodelet_manager/bond
> to have datatype/md5sum
> [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2/1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181],
> but our version has
> [bond/Status/eacc84bf5d65b6777d4c50f463dfb9c8].
> Dropping connection.

Basic question: Which is the topic to subscribe in rviz(where are the pcl2-msgs published) and is launchning the launchfile really all it takes to convert the raw data to pcl2-msgs?

Thanks a lot...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35592/displaying-velodyne---hdl-32e-data-in-rviz/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-06-04**:
My suspicion is that you are missing something that builds pointclouds out of VelodyneScans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you see, the [velodyne_driver](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne_driver) publishes `/velodyne_packets`, a device-dependent data stream that `rviz` does not understand.

As @dornhege said, you need to run one of the [velodyne_pointcloud](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne_pointcloud) nodes or nodelets. They will convert the raw Velodyne packets into `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2`, which `rviz` *can* display. That wiki page gives [some launch file examples](http://ros.org/wiki/velodyne_pointcloud#Launch_File_Examples) you may find helpful.

UPDATE: version 0.9.1 with the `32e_points.launch` file has just been released. You can either check out the new version and build it from source, or wait for the Debian packages to be updated (probably a few days).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-04**:
I added a paragraph to the driver overview, in an effort to make this clearer.

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-06-04**:
I've tried " $ roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch"(and the *.pcap-file version) but still,there is no topic that publishes pcl2 data?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-05**:
That launch file was not in the 0.9.0 release. It will be in 0.9.1, coming out today.